# :empty selector on tbody tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Given the following table:

```
<table id="incidents">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jQuery the following evaluate as `false`:

```
$("#incidents tbody").is(":empty")
```

I would like to use CSS to set the content to be a message:

```css
#incidents tbody:empty {
    content: "<tr>message foo</tr>";
}
```

Can the `:empty` selector be applied to tbody?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, unfortunately the indentation and newlines within `tbody` prevent it from ever matching `:empty` in this case. This applies both to [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector), where as far as I know `:empty` behaves identically, as well as jQuery's [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector), which is equivalent to `:not(:empty)` (with a *very* poor choice of name).

Furthermore, [you cannot use CSS `content` to add elements to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-inserting-html-instead-string/4505130#4505130). You'll need to do this in jQuery or the server side: check if `tbody` has any rows and if not, add that row.

If you go with jQuery, you can use this:

```
var tbody = $("#incidents tbody");

if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
    tbody.html("<tr>message foo</tr>");
}
```

Comment: "No, unfortunately the indentation and newlines within tbody prevent it from ever matching." Thanks, saved me some CSS debugging time.

Answer (score 3):

In this case tbody contains white space as content, so it won't work

[:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty)

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at
>   all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are
>   considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether
>   an element is considered empty or not.

Also the [:content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) can be used only with [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/%3a%3abefore) or [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo elements

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
>   using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are not pseudo-classes. They're pseudo-elements. It says so right in the quote.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `:empty` then you need to give the tbody syntax like as:

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

As you have define the :empty will not check that as it have a new line.

Define the `tbody`  as I have told you.
You can also use the `.html()` to check the condition:

```
if(!$("#incidents tbody").html()) {}
```

Reference:
[How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The `<tbody>` isn't empty, as it contains whitespace. You'll have to use a filtering function to get around that:

```
$("#incidents tbody").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim($(this).text());
}).append('<tr>message foo</tr>');
```

Or count the number of children:

```
$("#incidents tbody").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).children().length;
}).append('<tr>message foo</tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: You can use the following jQuery selector to select a table with an empty tbody without depending on the id of the table element:

```
$("table:not(:has(>tbody>tr))")
```

Answer (score 1):

Only CSS in 2023:

```
    tbody:not(:has(>tr)) {
      position: relative;
      height: 10em;
    }

    tbody:not(:has(>tr)):before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      content: 'message foo';
      color: #aaa;
      top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Comment: In general a good solution, but [`:has`](https://caniuse.com/css-has) is not supported by Firefox currently.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#incidents tbody").html()
```

and then check what you get.

Answer (score -1):

Check for this:

```
<table id="incidents">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```