# Stacked icons with one css class

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

In new FontAwesome 4.0.0 there is css styles for stacked items.

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

.fa-stack {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fa-stack-1x,
.fa-stack-2x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
.fa-stack-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.fa-stack-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.fa-square-o:before {
  content: "\f096";
}
```

[image]

I want to do it only without using nested `span` and `i`, just only with some css-classes

```
.myclass1 { ... }
.myclass2 { ... }
<span class=".... myclass2" />
```

What is the simplest method to achieve the same result (using fa content classes ?)

**Update**: 
or is something like the following possible ?

```
 .myclass1:before { content:     '<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>' }

     <span class=".... myclass1" />
```

Comment: Do you mean with a single `span` with both classes for square and twitter icons? You can't use `:before` twice on the same element (second declaration for `content` will override the first one) but there may still have a solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it explains something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edited)

This is not possible with `fa-*` classes, because there is no possibility to determine the order of stacked icons: in CSS `class="foo bar"` is the same as `class="bar foo"`

On the other side, you can define your own class and style it to achieve **one chosen stacked icon** - i.e you'll need one custom class per every pair (e.g `fa-times` stacked on `fa-square`).

In order to achieve this, use `:before` and `:after` selectors (and absolute positioning - [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn5e2/)).

It also seems (tested using `background` property) that `:after` element is on top of `:before` if you use absolute positioning. In case that's not true, you cvan always use `z-index` to order those two elements manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would be it possible to do something like: `.myclass {content: "<span..><i></i><i></></span>"} `. And what do you mean with positioning issues for :after? I've updated my question

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question. But would be it possible to use it with html code as content

Comment: as documentation says, html can't be used as a value of `content` attribute. I'm digging the `:after` case right now, it may work *in some cases*.

Comment: @Tony, I have achieved desired result with `:after`, but this still has some limitations. I hope you'll be satisfied, though. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is possible to reach the same (nice) result as with fa-* css styles to stack icons, if I use absolute position and :after?

Comment: If I understood your question well then yes, you should be able the get any desired result as this is fully customizable. Just fiddle a bit with `font-size`, '`top`, '`left` and (possibly) `color`.

Answer (score 3):

About your update, if something like the following possible ?

```
.myclass1:before { 
   content:'<span class="fa-stack">
      <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>' 
}

<span class=".... myclass1" />
```

It's not, as it is explained there : [CSS content property: is it possible to insert HTML instead of Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text)

If you want to keep control of the two stacked icon in a single HTML tag you can get it with something like that.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}

i:before {
    content: attr(icon-before); // "\f099";
    position: absolute; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin:0.1em;
}

i:after {
    content: attr(icon-after); // "\f096";
    position: absolute; 
    font-size: 2.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600464/html-special-characters-in-css-content-using-attr-->

<div><i class="fa" icon-before="&#xf099" icon-after="&#xf096"></i></div>
```