# html special characters in css content, using attr()

Tags: html, css, pug, pseudo-element, css-content

Relevant codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ocptF/

EDIT: The codepen uses Jade, and thus messes a few things up. I was not aware of this when starting this question.
Essentially, I thought CSS attr() would copy over an HTML attribute literally, but that is not the case.

I'd like to use the CSS `attr` function to fill in the `content` for some pseudoelements. However, it prints out `004` when the HTML attribute is set to `\f004`, and `08fa` when `\f08fa`.

Relevant lines:

HTML:

```
<div class="zoomfade" data-fill='\f004' data-unfill='\f08a'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.zoomfade:before {
  content: attr(data-unfill);
  position: absolute;
}

.zoomfade:before {
  content: attr(data-fill);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the question is about jade then you should include the jade tag and include the jade code in your question.  The correct answer is different whether you look at the actual code in the question or the jade in the codepen.

Comment: Jade doesn't have an effect on this not working. The error was assuming that the css attr function would use the html attribute literally.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. You're right. The source of my confusion was incorrect. I've added the `jade` tag to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape sequences in CSS are only treated specially in CSS syntax. When you specify it in an HTML attribute value then use that value in CSS `attr()`, it is taken literally. From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content):

> **attr(X)**
>   This function returns as a string the value of attribute X for the subject of the selector. The string is not parsed by the CSS processor. [...]

Since you're specifying character codes in HTML attribute values, you can either use HTML character references, entity references or the Unicode characters themselves. It's worth noting that the two character codes you have do not appear to be valid, however, so they may not work at all.

> EDIT: [...] Essentially, I thought CSS attr() would copy over an HTML attribute literally, but that is not the case.

It copies the attribute value according to the DOM, which may be different from how it is represented in the source, e.g. the source markup, or the script that is generating the element.

For example, if the source is represented in raw HTML markup, then as I mention above, you will need to use HTML character escapes, because HTML is parsed by an HTML parser. If the elements are generated using a JS-based template engine such as Jade, then the character escapes take the form of `\u` followed by the hexadecimal code-points. In both cases, the respective parsers will translate the escape sequences into their representative characters, and the characters themselves are what is stored in the DOM as part of the attribute value.

Of course, again there's always the alternative of just using the Unicode characters directly. If your source files are all encoded as UTF-8, you should have no problem using the characters directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though, using `data-fill="&#xf004;"` does not work, whereas using `data-fill=\uf004` does.

Comment: `&#xf004;` cant work. CSS cant parse HTML. `\uXXXX` is the right direction

Comment: @aaronz It sure does work if you actually create a codepen that represents your question rather than using jade:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wcznm/\

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks for that, but my question was using `\f004` rather than `&#xf004;`.

Comment: @aaronz: Those are two different representations of the same character: one in CSS, the other in HTML.

Comment: @Adrian Preuss: Like the quoted text says, the string is not parsed by CSS at all. As long as the context is HTML, you use character escapes that are specific to HTML.

Comment: By the way, regarding the fact that these are 2 invalid char codes - I'm trying to use http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: @aaronz: Ahhh, that explains it.