# CSS attr() - Set FontAwesome glyph dynamically inside before/after

Tags: html, css, attributes, font-awesome, attr

I'm trying to dynamically set a FontAwesome glyph inside a span or a button through the CSS property ***attr(property)***.

What I would like to have is to set an attribute on the tag

```
<button glyph="\f005"></button>
```

and then use it in the CSS file like this

```
button::before{
     content: attr(glyph)
}
```

But it looks like it doesn't work and it just display the code I've written in the tag. Is there a way to "render" the code or to make the CSS consider it as an escaped character?

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/pr1srrLj/) for a quick example.

Comment: Not that I've found, this usually requires JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097807/using-attrdata-icon-property-to-display-unicode-before-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600464/html-special-characters-in-css-content-using-attr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the value of the glyph attribute to a HTML entity, such as `glyph="&#xf005;"`

Comment: Direct and easy, I don't know what I was thinking about, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your CSS should be `button::before` or `button::after`, not only `button`. You can use `content` only in these.

Second, in HTML, you write entities like `&XXXX;`, not `\XXXX`, you mixed it up a little. Imagine it that the entity becomes single character and then it is transferred into CSS, not in another way. In HTML, you need to use HTML entities and in CSS, use CSS entities, even though they will travel through both languages in some way.

And third, don't use non-standard attributtes like `glyph`. They should be prepended with `data-`.

See http://codepen.io/ondrakoupil/pen/XbBvzV

Comment: Excuse me, the ::before was just a typo, in the Fiddle it was correct. You were correct about the '\' entity instead, I just replaced '\' with &#x as @tenderloin stated and it worked flawlessy. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the fiddle properly. Hope it will help!