# Ionic with fontawesome, stacked icons

Tags: css, ionic-framework, font-awesome

i'm trying to stack those two icon in a ionic icon. I know how to make the custom ionic icon, no problem. I also know about the `:before` and `:after` trick to stack icon from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591087/5784924)

For now, i got this css.

```
.ion-md-notice:before, .ion-ios-notice:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    content: '\f133' !important;
    bottom: -0.25em;
    position: relative;
    color: #d81717;
}

.ion-md-notice:after, .ion-ios-notice:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    content: '\f05e' !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.8em;
    color: #d81717;
}
```

Here is the HTML,

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let eventItem of dayEvents" text-wrap>
        <ion-icon [name]="eventItem.icon" item-left></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="create" item-right color="secondary" (click)="addEvent(eventItem)"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="trash" item-right color="danger" (click)="removeEvent(eventItem)"></ion-icon>
        <p class="title">{{eventItem.title | slice: 0: 30}}</p>
        <p class="subtitle" *ngIf="eventItem.description">{{eventItem.description | slice: 0: 40}}...</p>
        <p class="times">{{eventItem.start | date: 'shortTime'}} - {{eventItem.end | date: 'shortTime'}}</p>
      </ion-item>
```

final result :

```
<ion-icon item-left="" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-ios-notice item-icon" aria-label="notice" ng-reflect-name="notice"></ion-icon>
```

I manage to make it fit for one size of icon, no problem, 
[image]
But when I try to use the icon elsewhere, the icon does not fit anymore.
[image]
Please note that in the second images, the font are bigger.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be great to see your html, or even better a code snippet.

Comment: There is not much HTML involve. I'm using dynamic icon name.

Comment: Actually I wanted to see the final HTML displaying `.ion-md-notice` class as it's where your CSS is being applied to. But not Ionic-Angular stuff. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, right. Comming right up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the snippet below. The CSS part. Probably you'll have to adjust classes and set the desired font-size to `.item-icon`.

```css
.item-icon {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: relative;
  font-size: 60px
}

.item-icon:before {
  content: '\f133';
  color: #d81717;
}

.item-icon:after {
  content: '\f05e';
  font-size: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: .8em;
  left: .5em;
  color: #d81717;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ion-icon item-left="" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-ios-notice item-icon" aria-label="notice" ng-reflect-name="notice"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Happy to help !