# Can I use the pseudo element to insert html element?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert an html element after all my `li` s.
For example:
Html:

```
<ul>
 <li>some text</li>
 <li>some text</li>
 <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
li:after{
  content:"<div class="someclass"></div>";
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: content inserts textnode contents. you can't have it change the DOM structure. CSS's job is for styling. it's not there to modify the physical structure of things.

Comment: You need javascript for this, can't do it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you [can't do that with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4505130/4652564). But it's possible in JavaScript, for instance with [jQuery `.append();` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```js
// Add Baz to .myList
$( ".myList" ).append($("<li>Baz</li>"));
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myList">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks , that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show some graphic element after each li element the option is to use an url in the content property:

```
content: url(/pictures/logo.gif);
```