# How to put html code in pseudo element's content attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can put html code in content attribute of pseudo element `:after` in pure css ? if not with javascript.

```
.foo:after {
    content: 'foo<br/>moo';
}
```

it display me :

```
foo<br/>moo
```

not

```
foo
moo
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? css should just be used for stylings...

Comment: I don't think so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text

Comment: The `content` just takes only text, and not HTML. Case closed. `:)`

Comment: But if you want to line break with CSS content, you can use `\a`: `content: 'foo\amoo';`