# create and use a CSS form in <Style>, not in <Body> with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just have learnt HTML recently and have a small program.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.triangleright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent green ;
}

.triangledown {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-color: white transparent transparent transparent ;
}

button.accordion {
    background-color: rgb(213,227,233);
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active {
    background-color: rgb(0,56,96);
    color: white;
}

button.accordion:after {
    /* content:"/2795"; */
    content: "<div class="triangleright"></div>";
    font-size: 13px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    /* content:"/2796"; */
    content: "<div class="triangledown"></div>";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">&nbsp; &nbsp; Title</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

I need to create a small triange before "Title". But when I insert the triangle form which i have created into `button.accordion:after` and `button.accordion.active:after`, that does not work.

Comment: can't put html in css `content`

Comment: check once : [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)

Comment: @user: See my updated answer and fiddle link, probably you need to little bit of CSS modifications otherwise it will work perfect.

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you! I did not know about that

Comment: @RohitGoyani: thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create html elements in content property of CSS, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text)

Alternatively you can have another approach, you can put that button in a div, and in the div you can have an absolute position element which shows arrow, and you can handle that div same as you have handle nextElementSibling...

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/69cqf34o/3/) which solves your issue

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="arrow triangleright"></div>
  <button class="accordion">&nbsp; &nbsp; Title</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var accdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    onAccClick(this);
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < accdiv.length; i++) {
  accdiv[i].onclick = function() {
    onAccClick(this.nextElementSibling);
  }
}

function onAccClick(elem) {
    elem.classList.toggle("active");
  elem.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  elem.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("triangledown");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.triangleright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
}

.triangledown {
  top: 22px !important;
  right: 13px !important;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
}
div.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.accordion {
  background-color: rgb(213, 227, 233);
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 56, 96);
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  position: relative
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I just realize that with this method when we click directly to the triangle, it does not work, only when we click outside the triangle, it will work. Is there anything way to improve this ?

Comment: @htmlamateur : Updated your case aswell, registered an event on that div as well, to expand the accordion view, have a look  at it, also updated the fiddle

Comment: thanks alot Parag! I have enough reputation and upvoted for you already. Thank you again Parag ! :)