# Html tags not rendering with tooltip

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to render html tag inside the tooltip but tags are coming as text. i don't want to use JQuery. Is there any way to achieve this.

```
link jsfiddle ->
```

[Demolink](http://jsfiddle.net/gLeydk0k/411/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text

Answer (score 0):

Simply render it as plain HTML, but hide it with `ng-show` / `ng-if`.
Then reveal it on hover with `ng-mouseover` + `ng-mouseleave`.

Here is the simplest demo:

```css
.ellipsis {
  content: attr(data-title);
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  background: #191919;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  opacity: 1.1;
  margin-top: 0rem;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>

    <input ng-model="i" ng-mouseover="a=true" ng-mouseleave="a=false" />
    <div class="ellipsis" ng-if="a"><b>Hypertext</b> Markup Language</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="ii" ng-mouseover="aa=true" ng-mouseleave="aa=false" />
    <div class="ellipsis" ng-if="aa"><b>Hypertext</b> Markup Language</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="iii" ng-mouseover="aaa=true" ng-mouseleave="aaa=false" />
    <div class="ellipsis" ng-if="aaa"><b>Hypertext</b> Markup Language</div>
    <br>
    <br>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```