# AngularJS - render HTML to tooltip

Tags: html, css, angularjs, tooltip

So basically I am displaying some text with `ng-bind-html` on page as text consist of html element and i have requirement to show the same text when hover your mouse over it.

i have created css class which will show the same text on hover but html tag coming as a text. i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text) which says it's not possible.

I am using angularjs, below is html

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
    <p class="ellipsis" ng-bind-html="bar" data-text="{{bar}}"></p>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']).controller('foo', function($scope) {
$scope.bar = "<h1>this is bar</h1>"; }); 

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

[demolink](https://jsfiddle.net/tbutbap3/660/)

Is it possible to render it as plain HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS content property: is it possible to insert HTML instead of Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because css `content: attr();`     in your case:

```
.ellipsis:focus:after, .ellipsis:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-text);
```

only accept allowed list of types. The list does not contains html/ html tags.
Here are allowed types:

```
<type-or-unit> = string | integer | color | url | integer | number | length | angle | time | frequency | em | ex | px | rem | vw | vh | vmin | vmax | mm | q | cm | in | pt | pc | deg | grad | rad | ms | s | Hz | kHz | %
```

There are some experiment by including hexadecimal values there but html tags will not works.

Here are more details about it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: thanks @nezir. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, please check this code also here is working sample https://jsfiddle.net/nezir/tbutbap3/667/ can update by you can update by your needs.

I have change the text and removed h1 tags from text. Also, updated the css, so default text class will use default h1 font size which is in most cases `2em` or 24px  and also added some bold property here like `font-weight: 700;`  which you

Also, updated hover class  `font-size: 1em;` .

I think that's you are requiring at the end. Generally, update css classes if you need to manipulate text value size or any other property.

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = "this is bar";
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);


.ellipsis {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight:700;
    }

    .ellipsis:focus:after, .ellipsis:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    background: #191919;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:0.4rem;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
     font-size: 1em;
    margin-right: 13px;
    opacity: 1.1;
    margin-top: 0rem;
}
```

Comment: I think you miss understood me. its not about just <h1> tag, it can be any html tag (<b>, <i>, <strong> etc.... can come.

Comment: no than its not possible to convert html tags into CSS attributes in the way your sample was written.

Comment: any other way you think this can achieve? i am open to make changes.