# Use inline SVG with HTML5 as a background in a DIV element

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm not very familiar with svgs. Please suggest anything I could use for the following situation.
I have two divs like the following. The first div generates an svg and the second div is a normal div. I want to use the SVG which is generating from the first div as the background for the second div(main-div). I don't want to use absolute/fixed positioning in here. Is there any way to do that except use positioning?

```html
<div class="svg-div" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <path d="M0.00,49.99 C150.00,150.00 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #08f;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="main-div"> 
  <ul> <li>a</li><li>b</li> </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the SVG dynamically generated or why do you want it to be inline?

Comment: Check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text/37558030#37558030

Comment: @biberman I generated it using an SVG generating site. I just want to display that kind of shape as the background for my lists

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to save SVG into an SVG file as it will be the most flexible for all browser.

After you can use the `position` even though you don't want.

Finaly after searching a bit more, I found out a subject using URI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text/37558030#37558030).

**But pay attention that it might not work in all browser (specialy olds ones).**

So I search for a [URI-Converter to SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

And the output is:

```css
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 150' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='height: 100%25; width: 100%25;'%3E%3Cpath d='M0.00,49.99 C150.00,150.00 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z' style='stroke: none; fill: %2308f;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

### Demo

```css
.svg-div{
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 150' preserveAspectRatio='none' style='height: 100%25; width: 100%25;'%3E%3Cpath d='M0.00,49.99 C150.00,150.00 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z' style='stroke: none; fill: %2308f;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-div" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="main-div"> 
    <ul> <li>a</li><li>b</li> </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly, you need to add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to your svg element.
- Then, use the following JavaScript to set the background image.

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svgCode = window.btoa(svg.outerHTML);

document.getElementById('main-div').style.backgroundImage = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64," + svgCode + ")";
```

```html
<div class="svg-div" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<path d="M0.00,49.99 C150.00,150.00 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #08f;"></path>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="main-div">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Read this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/what-purpose-does-xmlns-http-www-w3-org-2000-svg-version-1-1-serve/277084/2) to understand why `xmlns` is required.