# Place an HTML element top of all elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to develop a Tooltip using CSS to use with [Select2](https://select2.org). I used `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 99999;` for the Tooltip. But the Tooltip is not appearing above all HTML element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    placeholder: "select...",
    templateSelection: function(state) {
      if (!state.id) {
        return state.text;
      }      
      return $(`<span>${state.text}</span>`);
    },
    templateResult: function(state) {
      if (!state.id) {
        return state.text;
      }      
      return $("<span class='tooltip'>" +
            state.text +
            "<span class='tooltiptext'>" +
            state.value +
            "</span></span>");
    },
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/public',
      dataType: 'json',
      processResults: function(data) {        
        var options = [];
          if (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                  options.push({
                    id: index,
                    text: text.owner.login,
                    value: text.commits_url,
                  });
              });
          }
          return {
              results: options,
              more: false,
          };
      },
      data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.js-data-example-ajax {
  width: 200px;
}

.top{
  color:red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: fit-content;
  z-index:100000;
}


.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 620px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: -30%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select class="js-data-example-ajax" id="mySelect2" multiple>
</select>
```

Here is the issue.

[image]

Could you please help me to show the Tooltip above all the HTML elements ?

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code, your image shows that the tooltip is a child element of the select2 dropdown, so is limited to that elements dimensions.  Move it to document so that it's not constrained (if possible, might need some major changes to how it's generated)

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m. Could you please guide me fix the issue ? I need a Tooltip on Select2 values. I am fighting with for last couple of days. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m. How can I move Tooltip to document ? Thanks.